# How to use xargs with BSD find?

Tags: shell, find, portability, xargs, bsd

With GNU `find`, it is easy to pipe to `xargs`. A typical (useless) example:

```
find /var/log -name "*.log" | xargs dirname
```

This returns all the directory names containing some log file.

The same command with BSD `find` does not work, ending with:

```
usage: dirname path
```

That is `xargs` is unable to pass file list entries to `dirname`.

BSD `find`'s manpage mentions the `-exec` and `-execdir` options, stating "This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1)."

> -exec utility [argument ...] {} +
>               Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for
>               each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1).
>
> -execdir utility [argument ...] {} +
>               Same as -execdir, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible
>               for each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1).

Each time I fall back on these two flags, I have to read the documentation again. I seem unable to remember their usage! Also, I am concerned with script portability across GNU/BSD systems, basically Linux, Open/FreeBSD, and MacOS.

Any way to pipe BSD `find` to `xargs`, or `-exec` is really the only option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both GNU and FreeBSD version of `xargs` support a way to pass the strings from stdin to the command as part of the `-I` flag. All you need to is

```
find /var/log -name "*.log" | xargs -I {} dirname -- "{}"
```

The GNU `xargs` page says about the flag as

> `-I replace-str`
>   Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.

This provides an alternate way than using `-exec` or `-execdir`. However, having said, that using `-exec` is not too complex for your case.

```
find /var/log -name "*.log" -type f -exec dirname "{}" \;
```

Comment: would you know why BSD `xargs` causes that error? I just ran into it piping the output of `echo` to `xargs dirname`. Curiously, it works fine with `args basename`.

Comment: On further viewing, this isn't working as expected. The line piped in from `echo` is being processed as one single line.

Comment: @NoelYap The answer is based on the OP, if you have a different input coming in, please ask a different question, stating what is not working to get assist on that